# When  can't I play an MP3 file in Banshee?

Tags: banshee, multimedia, mp3, codecs

I wanted to play media files on Banshee but it seems there is a huge problem in it. All the music gets loaded but when I select a song and press play button nothing happens. More than that when I try to play some MP3 on Movie player error pops up saying - "Could not determine type of stream."

I have already installed the updates needed to run MP3 files and other stuff. My MK5 videos are playing perfectly. Banshee gives no such errors but fails to run. What will solve my problem. Reinstalling Banshee after uninstalling or reinstalling the system updates?

I checked whether is was something wrong with Unity. But it wasn't. Even this happens in y Gnome. Is this some kind of a bug?

Comment: May I know which version of Ubuntu are you using and what package have you installed for playing the MP3 files?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 - I used this - sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Comment: the ability to play mp3 requires patent, and copyright encumbered software, which is not distributed with Ubuntu. Try Ubuntu-restricted-extras.

Comment: Then perhaps we need more information and testing to solve this issue.

Comment: How can I give you more information?

Answer (score 7):

As noted in [Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats), by default, Ubuntu tries to only include completely free software means that proprietary media formats are not configured 'out of the box'. However, extra packages can be installed to play those proprietary media format.

To play the proprietary media format, install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package.

You can do it by doing one of the following:

1. Clicking on [this link](http://apt%3aubuntu-restricted-extras?section=universe?section=multiverse).
2. Start the Ubuntu Software Centre, search for '`ubuntu-restricted-extras`', and click on the install button.
3. Execute the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` in Terminal.

Comment: I was able to play my MP3 files in Banshee by doing so. I am not sure what packages you have installed. But this should serve as a solution for most people as well.